# Python multiprocessing pool within Class method

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pathos, starmap

### Context

I am trying to use multiprocessing, specifically `Pool().starmap()`, within a specific method of a class. Let's name the file with the code for the **Quant** class **model.py**. I'd like to be able to import **Quant**, declare an instance of it, `myobj`, and call `myobj.calculate()` from another file called **tester.py**. My overall goal here is to get **tester.py** to run as fast as possible, with the cleanest syntax possible.

**model.py**

```
import multiprocessing
from optcode import optimizer

def f(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    return arg1.run(arg_a = arg2, arg_b=arg3, arg_c=arg4)

Class Quant
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

   def calculate(self):

      optimization = optimizer()
      args = [(optimization, x, y, z),(optimization, q, r, z), (optimization, l, m, n)]

      cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
      with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpus) as pool:
         tasks = pool.starmap(f, args)
  
      self.results = tasks
```

**tester.py**

```
from model import Quant

if __name__ == '__main__':
   
   myobj = Quant('My Instance')
   myobj.calculate()
   print(myobj.results)
```

### Questions

1. From what I can tell, the `myobj.calculate()` line needs to be within `if __name__ == '__main__':` to prevent everything from freezing (a fork bomb?). It appears that when I move the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line up to include everything within **tester.py** (as I have in the above example), it then prevents Python from re-importing (and executing) **tester.py** ncpu times when I execute **tester.py** once.
   Is my understanding correct, and is there an alternative to needing to use these conditions? Trying to set things up for less saavy users. My actual application has more computationally intensive code within both `Quant.__init__()` and `Quant.calculate()`.
2. How else can I speed this up (more) ? I have read that `pathos.multiprocessing` has superior serialization. Would that help in this context? In my actual application, `args[0]` is a tuple of pandas DataFrames and floats.
   I have also read that there may be a better type of mapping to use with the processing pool. I do need the result of the pool to be ordered the same way as args, but I don't need intermediate results from each worker process; each process is totally independent of one another. Would something like `imap()` or `map_async()` make for a more efficient setup?
   I haven't been able to get the syntax for pathos to work and I've read all the examples I can find. Something about `args[0]` being a tuple of arguments, and `args` itself being an iterable (list) seems to be the issue. I know `pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool().map()` can handle multi-arg functions, but I can't figure out how to use it, given the structure of my inputs.

Comment: It seems you want an ensemble of optimizers running in parallel. You might try `mystic`, which can utilize `pathos` for just such a thing.  If you prefer the `multiprocessing` interface over that in `pathos`, you can use `multiprocess` to get the same serialization benefits with the same interface as `multiprocessing`.